# Python : Using ArcPy : Sorting Access Tables and Converting to Geodatabase Tables

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy

I like to convert tables (100+) living in access database to a geodatabase tables, sorting them and deleting unnecessary fields in each table at the same time. I figured I use the Sort_management method to convert and sort the tables followed by DeleteFieldd_management method to delete the fields. Here is the code that I have written,

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "E:\Database Project\ACS Estimate 2011\ACS 2011 Tables.mdb"

tableList = arcpy.ListTables()

for table in tableList:

    out_dataset = "E:\Database Project\ACS Estimate 2011\Data\To Database\Seq Tables.gdb"

    #Process: Sort
    arcpy.Sort_management(table, out_dataset, "GEOID ASCENDING", "UR")

    #Process: Delete Field
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(out_dataset, "FILEID;FILETYPE;STUSAB;CHARITER")
```

I am getting the following error message,

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `out_dataset` before entering the loop (immediately after `tableList = arcpy.ListTables()` and see if it gets past the "already exists" error.

Answer (score 0):

to follow on @Evan, you could erase the table if it pre-exists.

```
if arcpy.Exists(out_dataset):
    arcpy.Delete_management(out_dataset)
```

Also, if I know I'm going to be recreating a table over and over and I don't want to write checks like this into my code, I use:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
```

If this table type isn't really recognized by arcpy, then you could do an analogous "if-exists" thing w/just python's os module or something else along those lines.